# Jenkins 2.89 SVN Checkout FAILURE java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

All jobs using SVN Checkout are now failing. 
Running Jenkins 2.89, SVN 1.92, SUSE 12-SP2
Running Master only

SVN Checkout from a command line window is successful.

Jenkins job receives:

```
Building in workspace /var/devops/jenkins/jobs/svn test/workspace
Cleaning local Directory CCUMMINGS_TEST_PHASE2
Checking out https://99.999.88.111/MAIN/branches/CCUMMINGS_TEST_PHASE2 at revision '2018-06-12T11:04:05.109 -0700'
FATAL: null
java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1127)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.fs.SqlJetFileLockManager$1.createLock(SqlJetFileLockManager.java:57)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.fs.SqlJetFileLockManager.createLock(SqlJetFileLockManager.java:81)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.fs.SqlJetFileLockManager.tryLock(SqlJetFileLockManager.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.fs.SqlJetFile.checkReservedLock(SqlJetFile.java:714)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.pager.SqlJetPager.hasHotJournal(SqlJetPager.java:2484)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.pager.SqlJetPager.sharedLock(SqlJetPager.java:1251)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.pager.SqlJetPager.acquirePage(SqlJetPager.java:1020)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.btree.SqlJetBtree.getMeta(SqlJetBtree.java:2196)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.table.SqlJetOptions.readSchemaCookie(SqlJetOptions.java:213)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.table.SqlJetOptions.readMeta(SqlJetOptions.java:148)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.internal.table.SqlJetOptions.<init>(SqlJetOptions.java:104)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine$2.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:281)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.runSynchronized(SqlJetEngine.java:217)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.readSchema(SqlJetEngine.java:276)
    at org.tmatesoft.sqljet.core.table.engine.SqlJetEngine.getOptions(SqlJetEngine.java:299)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDbRoot.<init>(SVNWCDbRoot.java:74)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc17.db.SVNWCDb.parseDir(SVNWCDb.java:1984)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.isVersionedDirectory(SvnOperationFactory.java:1502)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.isVersionedDirectory(SvnOperationFactory.java:1480)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCUtil.isVersionedDirectory(SVNWCUtil.java:296)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.getImplementation(SvnOperationFactory.java:1318)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1227)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.CheckoutUpdater$1.perform(CheckoutUpdater.java:121)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:168)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:1041)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:1017)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:997)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:975)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:937)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:864)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1202)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1724)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I suspect a password or a credential may be off, but none of them have changed.

a jenkins pipeline job with a script from SVN can be checked out and run but gets the same error.

Any help in debugging or direction to look in would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins .xml files had been placed under SVN control using command line svn. Removed .svn files from Jenkins directory and var/devops/jenkins/jobs directory and ../jenkins/jobs directory to resolve the error